# Dark Souls Upgrade to "Prepare To Die"-Edition (PS3)

Tags: dark-souls

I own the PS3-version of Dark Souls and have already played it for some time. Now I would like to get the DLC "Artorias of the Abyss", but instead of downloading it, I would like to purchase the "Prepare To Die"-Edition, mainly for its extra content.

The questions are:

Does the "Prepare To Die"-Edition install seperately from the original game or does it integrate?

Does the PtD-Edition install a seperate trophy set?

And most importantly: Can I still use the saves that I already have in the game?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 1):

From the information I have seen,  the Prepare to Die edition creates a new save that does not access the old save.  This means it does not delete old save but does not access the old save either.  You best bet for continuing from your save data is just to download the DLC.

But here is a forum where they are asking the same question.
[Do save files and trophies carry over to 'Prepare to Die' Edition?](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/dark-souls/177282-do-save-files-trophies-carry-over-prepare-die-edition.html)

Comment: well, most of the answers in the forum thread you linked say that it's not working so they oppose what you're saying, but they may not be reliable. Do you have experience with this yourself? Also, I have the German USK-version if that makes any difference.

Comment: Yeah the more digging I did it seems there are mixed results depending on the region of the game.  In my experience the save did transfer over.  I am unsure what region though mine was because it was a while ago.  But a lot of places are just saying if you download the DLC that it definitely is ok and can continue off your same save.  So maybe that would be the safer route for you?

Comment: yes, I knew that downloading the DLC should work, but that's not really what I wanted to do. The PtD-Edition has become quite cheap and includes things I'd like to have such as an artbook and the soundtrack, so it seems more worth the money than just downloading. That aside, I have a UK-PSN-account which makes it likely that it won't work with my disc version. Did you have both disc versions when you transferred your saves or the downloaded DLC?

Comment: I just went back and checked my discs and I was mistaken, I had re-bought the original disc and downloaded the DLC.  From what I was reading on some other reviews is that the Prepare to Die edition doesn't access the same save.  So it won't overwrite the old save from the original but it will not transfer to the Prepare to Die edition.  Edited my answer to include what we have discussed.

Comment: Yes, I searched some more as well and for most people it doesn't seem to work. It seems I'll have to download it then. Thanks for taking the time to help me, anyway. I'll keep this as unanswered for people to confirm it who tried it themselves.